# Routing error with devise {:controller=>"devise/static", :action=>"about"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I got a problem with devise. Every time I try to call an Url that should be handled by devise (e.g. http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up) I end up with the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/static", :action=>"about"}
```

Hopefully somebody can help me!

---

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users

get "pages/contact"
get "pages/imprint"
get "pages/about"

root :to => "pages#about"
```

**What I did:**

Added `gem 'devise'` to the gemfile

```
bundle install 
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
```

**rake routes**

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
           pages_contact GET    /pages/contact(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
           pages_imprint GET    /pages/imprint(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"imprint"}
             pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)         {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
                    root        /                              {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
```

**Rails Version:** 
Rails 3.1.3

---

**PagesController**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact
  end

  def imprint
  end

  def about
  end

end
```

Comment: I've followed your steps on Rails 3.1.3 and I can't reproduce the issue you're having. It seems to be a problem of Devise interfering with your non-Devise routes, but I can't see why that would happen. Is there anything odd going on in your PagesController by any chance?

Comment: I added the content of the page controller (it is just what was generated by the rails g command). My Rails version is 3.1.3 too...

Comment: Strange, I just found out that the problem might be. In the application.html.erb... I had three links to the pages in the PagesController ... <%= link_to "Imprint",  :controller => :pages, :action => :imprint %> If I remove them the error is gone. But why?

Comment: [This guy](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/dca45ef8cf7b94a9/ad2791ec4bdd7f9a?show_docid=ad2791ec4bdd7f9a) seems to have the same problem, and the solution is just to use a named route instead. However it would be interesting to see exactly what's happening for Devise to cause this behaviour.

Comment: I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226107/devise-invitable-routing-error but haven't found a solution for it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error for me was fixed when I changed my `link_to` methods.

In my header I had:

```
<%= link_to "Info", :controller => :info %>
```

and when I switched it to:

```
<%= link_to "Info", "/info" %>
```

the error was gone!

Comment: I had the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226107/devise-invitable-routing-error  and your suggestions resolved. Thx.