# Routing Error with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

My app contains belongings that are tagged. It uses Devise for user authentification.

I got the following routing error when linking to the "Forgot Password?" Devise link:

```
  No routes matches {:controller => "devise/belongings", :action => "with_tag", :tag_id => 1}
```

The link issuing this error is

```
 <%= link_to "tagname", {:controller => :belongings, :action => :with_tag, :tag_id => t.id} %>
```

My routing file contains :

```
 resources :belongings do
   get 'with_tag', :on => :collection
   get 'remove_tag', :on => :collection
 end
```

and

```
 devise_scope :user do
     get "sign_in", :to => "sessions#new"
     get "sign_out", :to => "devise/session#destroy"
     get "sign_up", :to => "devise/registration#new"
 end
```

It is such as the routing is looking under the Devise scope for the route it has to follow.

One easy fix is to code the link as it:

```
   <%= link_to "tagname", {:controller => "/belongings", :action => :with_tag, :tag_id => t.id} %>
```

that forces the controller under the root directory without adding the Devise scope.

I find this solution completely ugly.

Could you propose a better one? For instance a better config on the route.rb?

Thks!

Comment: The correction mentioned above comes from the following question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474537/routing-error-with-devise-controller-devise-static-action-about)